# Unexpected behavior with Calendar class of Java

Tags: java, date, java-7

I have following code to get different parts of current system Date (10-11-2011 for this case).

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
String dt = ""+now.get(now.DATE)+"-"+now.get(now.MONTH)+"-"+now.get(now.YEAR);
```

Here, `DATE` and `YEAR` fields are giving values as expected but `MONTH` field is giving unexpected results, firstly I didn't knew that `MONTH` field starts with zero, so having current month as `11` will give me `10`. Now, if I use `now.get(now.MONTH+1)` than it returns `46`. And using simply `now.MONTH` instead of using `get` method gives `2`.

So, what am I doing wrong here? it shouldn't be a bug in Calendar class.

Note that I'm using JDK 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1`.

`now.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns the month starting at 0. And you need to add 1 to the result. If you do `now.get(Calendar.MONTH + 1)`, you're getting something other than the month, because you don't pass the MONTH constant to the get method anymore. get just takes an int as parameter. The constant MONTH means "I want to get the month". The constant DATE means "I want to get the date". Their value has no meaning. MONTH is 2, and 3 is WEEK_OF_YEAR.

Also note that static variables (or constants) should be accessed using the class name, and not an instance of the class.

Have you considered using `SimpleDateFormat`? That's the class to use to format a Date using a specific pattern:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(now.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Month is zero-indexed according to the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

and similarly for [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

You need to add 1 to it to display it numerically or use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which will do this automatically for you.

If you're doing a lot of work with dates, then I suggest using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead.  It is much better than the Java core library date/time handling.

> Joda-Time provides a quality replacement for the Java date and time classes. The design allows for multiple calendar systems, while still providing a simple API. The 'default' calendar is the ISO8601 standard which is used by XML. The Gregorian, Julian, Buddhist, Coptic, Ethiopic and Islamic systems are also included, and we welcome further additions. Supporting classes include time zone, duration, format and parsing.