# Date of birth issue in android

Tags: java, android

I am using below code for the date of birth in registration of the user, but when using it is getting the month of the birth one less, example birth month is September it is registering in database birth month as august, and this date of birth is being registered in numerics and format is dd/mm/yyyy

I want the accuracy with the month. please assist

```
public void showDateDialog() {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) ;
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                if (day < 10 && monthOfYear < 10)
                    date = "0" + dayOfMonth + "/0" + monthOfYear + "/" + year;


                else if (day < 10 && monthOfYear > 10)
                    date = "0" + dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year;

                else if (day > 10 && monthOfYear < 10)
                    date = dayOfMonth + "/0" + monthOfYear + "/" + year;

                else
                    date = dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year;

                dateOfBirth.setText(date);

            }
        };

        DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
        dpDialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: What part of your code is related to Firebase?

Comment: unfortunately the `Calendar` uses a month based on zero, that is January is 0, February is 1, .... it's suggested not to use that class anymore, the classes in the `java.time` package are more appropriate

Comment: @AlexMamo actually I am using firebase firestore database, that's why I mentioned it

Comment: @Ramneek Hello and welcome! Please add tags only if they're relevant to the question, not if you happen to use a certain technology in your app.

Comment: see [Unexpected behavior with Calendar class of Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8070826/85421) or [Calendar class confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8807438/85421) (or the [JANUARY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) constant and its [value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY) for example)

Comment: use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar count month from 0 to 11.

So that you get one month difference.So you add 1 always.

Answer (score 0):

```
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
```